# Is there a way in WiX to supress ICE on a case by case basis

Tags: wix, ice

Is there a way to do this. I don't want to shut off all of them from a certain ICE, because some may be valid and need fixing. But there are times I would like to say. OK, I can live with that ICE, there is no way around it and I just want to supress this instance. Can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, you want to suppress some errors from a given ICE but not the entire ICE.   If that is correct, no, this is not possible due to the design of Windows Installer.   ICE's are atomic.  The only work around would be to not use WiX to run your validation.   Come up with your own script that executes validation redirecting to an output and then parse the output for ICE errors that don't contain the specific error that you don't care about.

Comment: Dang that's what I was afraid of from my googling. If nobody has a workaround by tomorrow, Ill accept this as the answer.

Comment: I assure you, that is the answer. I have a bit of experience with MSI's, ICE's and CUB's. http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2009/02/msi-tip-authoring-ice-using-c-dtf.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature request for the WiX toolset to provide. It has never bubbled to the top. Want to implement it? :)

Comment: I would love to get it implemented, however I don't think I will have any real time to devote to it anytime soon. So, sadly, I will have to pass for now :) However, if the situtation changes maybe I will try.

Comment: I wish Microsoft would open source the ICE's so that we could get a community edition project going on.   Then we could make the tests more granular and avoid this problem in the first place.